# loop in razor shows conditional compilation is turned off

Tags: javascript, razor

This question maybe asked many times but I didn't get solution to my problem. So excuse !

[image: Conditional compilation error]

script-

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    @for (int i = 0; i < Model.Count; i++) {
        <text>var splitdata = new Array[

            "Model[i].AccountHead",
            Model[i].AccID
            ];</text>

    }
</script>
```

I am fetching model values in this loop. But I am not able to use this loop to fetch out records available in database, It is not even considering `i` in loop. Seems that loop is not working anymore.

How can I get it done?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
"@(Model[i].AccountHead)",
@(Model[i].AccID)
```

And forget conditional compilation is turned off warning :)

Do it like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
@for (int i = 0; i < Model.Count; i++) 
{
    var current = Model[i];
    <text>
    var splitdata = ["@current.AccountHead", @current.AccID];
    alert(JSON.stringify(splitdata)); // temp. use `splitdata` JavaScript array here
    </text>
}
</script>
```

Comment: this is not valid JavaScript syntax: `var splitdata = new Array[]`. do it like this: `var splitdata = []`;

Comment: Same as its in image here. I want only to run this loop.

Comment: Forget about that warning, that's not the cause of your problem

Comment: It shows Expected semicolon on `i` and loop never runs. What? have i done the loop thing okay?